# Concatenating two strings and making them the same size

Tags: java

If I have two strings, Hello and Java. they are not the same size. If I wanted to concatenate them but make the larger string the same size by omit'ing chars how would I go about it?

For example. Hello and Java would become elloJava and Day and test would become DayTes.

All I have so far is the comparison. The print text is placeholder

```
  if (a.length() != b.length())
    System.out.print("tt");
  else
    System.out.print("1");
```

I have no idea where to start.

Comment: What is the rule to truncate once the leading and once the trailing character?

Comment: Have a look at the subString method on the string class.

Comment: Do you mean `DayTes` or `Daytes`? Why does the `T` change case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first String is longer :

```
// omit characters from the start of the first String
System.out.print(a.substring(a.length-b.length)+b));
```

If the second String is longer :

```
// omit characters from the end of the second String
System.out.print(a+b.substring(0,a.length));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.substring`:

```
int minLength = Math.min(a.length(), b.length());
String concatenated = a.substring(a.length() - minLength) + b.substring(0, minLength);
```

Comment: This is wrong. As it would be `HellJava` instead of `elloJava`.

Comment: @SubOptimal I would assume that I can change it to the correct version using this method?

Comment: @Yazz Have a look at the answer from Eran. He mention a solution for both cases (if this is what you are looking for).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {

    String a="Hello";
    String b="Java";

    public void addString()
    {
        int minLength = Math.min(a.length(), b.length());
        String concatenated = a.substring(1, minLength+1) + b.substring(0, minLength);

        System.out.print("concatenated: "  +concatenated);

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test test=new Test();
        test.addString();
    }

}

O/P : concatenated : elloJava
```

Answer (score 0):

public class Test {

```
String a="Hello";
String b="Java";

public void addString()
{
    int minLength = Math.min(a.length(), b.length());
    String concatenated = a.substring(1, minLength+1) + b.substring(0, minLength);
```

OR

String concatenated=((a+b).substring(1,a.length())+b);

```
    System.out.print("concatenated: "  +concatenated);

}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Test test=new Test();
    test.addString();
}
```

}

O/P : concatenated : elloJava